# Why is the left button of a mouse the primary button by default?

Tags: usability, gui-design

By default, most computer users use the left button of the mouse in order to open a file or to perform other tasks. I know is it up to a user to configure the left or right button as the main button, but why does it default to the left and why do companies like Apple offer single-button mice?

Comment: Because you press things using your index finger, and the left button is where your index finger sits.

Comment: @JonW but you also presses things using other fingers, not only by index or trigger finger.

Comment: You _primarily_ press with your index finger, and you _also_ press with other fingers. The mouse button supports your primary behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The left-click operation is normally operated by the index (pointing) finger, which is [usually dominant](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0266768199902048) (being the most dextrous and sensitive). The left button of a mouse is configured as the primary button by default because that suits the vast majority (~90%) of right-handed users.